# Возникает ошибка UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0450' in position 3: character maps to
<undefined>
```

вот так выглядит эта ошибка в моей программе, которая работает с файлами, как можно ее исправить, подскажите пожалуйста

мой код:

```
def file_readlines():
    with open("Текст2.txt", 'r',encoding="cp1251") as f:
        return(f.read())



def shifr_file_readlines(file_message, key):
    s1=''
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    key=alf2.index(key)
    for c in file_message:
        if ord(c) in range(ord('а'), ord('я')+1): # если это символ а-я
            s1 += chr(ord('а') + (ord(c) - ord('а') + key)%33)
        elif ord(c) in range(ord('А'), ord('Я')+1): # если это символ А-Я
            s1 += chr(ord('А') + (ord(c) - ord('А') + key)%33)
        else: # иначе просто дописываем этот символ
            s1 += c
    return ''.join(s1)



def result_file_readlines(root,file_message,key):
    lbl_out = Label(root,text="Файл зашифрован", font=50)
    f=open("Текст2.txt","w")
    f.write(shifr_file_readlines(file_message,key))
    f.close()
    lbl_out.place(x=460,y=410)



btn_filelines_cezar = Button(root, text="Зашифровать многострочный файл шифром Цезаря",command=lambda: result_file_readlines(root,p,tp2.get()),
              font="Calibri 15",height=2,width=45,bg="green")


btn_filelines_cezar.place(x=0,y=390)
```

Comment: можно исправить, если вы покажете свой код

Comment: готово, простите, что так много, это проект

Comment: Напишите плиз номер строки с ошибкой

Comment: 19 линия,забыл написать

Comment: и вот, у меня файл сохраняется постоянно в кодировке ANSI, может проблема в этом?

Comment: Уберите из кода все, что не относится к ошибке.

Comment: изменил программу

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: а конкретно для моей программы?